# How do I fix this challenge of have any password login a user in on codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, authentication

I had been trying to fix a challenge I am having on my code which will allow any password to login a user to the dashboard. For instance, any user registered on the platform can use his email and any password to login in. The password is saved as hash in the database but when I want to login, in any password can login the user which should not be. For example 123456 will log in the user, and 656565656 can login in the same user. Please help me I know I am not getting it right somewhere but I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Here is my controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailid','Email id','required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[6]');
    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $emailid=$this->input->post('emailid');
        $password=password_verify($this->input->post('password'),$account->password);
        $status=1;  

        $this->load->model('User_Login_Model');
        $validate=$this->User_Login_Model->validatelogin($emailid,$password,$status);
        if($validate)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('uid',$validate);
            redirect('user/dashboard');
        } else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid details. Please try again with valid details');
            redirect('user/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model file for user login

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function validatelogin($emailid,$password,$status)
{

    $query=$this->db->where(['emailId'=>$emailid,'userPassword'=>$password]);
    $account=$this->db->get('tblusers')->row();
    if($account!=NULL)
    {
        $dbstatus=$account->isActive;
        //verifying status
        if( $dbstatus==$status)
        {
            return $account->id;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return NULL;
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Your accounis is not active contact admin');
            redirect('user/login');
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

[image: login.php file]

Comment: So you're trying to bypass the password? is that the simple way to put it? why even have `'userPassword'=>$password` ?

Comment: What is `$account` in your `index` function, doesn't seem to be set anywhere?

Comment: The `$account` is in the model file; `$account=$this->db->get('tblusers')->();`

Comment: It's not in the function scope

Comment: Please guide me on how I can do that.

Comment: Well, actually let's put it another way. Why are you calling `password_verify` in the main index function? It seems logical that verifying the password would be an important part of the `validatelogin` process? (Which is a place, of course, where you _do_ have an `$account` variable you can use.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is when you are trying to login to an account with the wrong password it still takes you to the user dashboard. Right?

It is because you are not comparing the password from the database.

Following is the code which may help you:

My_model.php

```
public function check_login_model(){
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM login_table WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
    $row = $query->row_array();
    $count = $query->num_rows();
    if ($count==1) {
        $this->session->login_user = $email;
    }else{
        return "No records found.";
    }
}
```

My_controller.php

```
public function index(){
    if ($this->session->login_user) { 
        $this->load->view('user/dashboard');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('user/login'); 
    }
}
```

I hope this simple login method may help you.

Comment: Thanks @Ajay Kushwaha. How about password verify

Comment: Do you realise that your code is fully open to sql injections ? - i strongly suggest to edit your answer - because it leads beginners to a very dangerous direction

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

The controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail address', 'required|valid_email')
        ->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        // validation errors
        var_dump(validation_errors());
    }
    else
    {

        $this->load->model('user_login_model');
        $user = $this->user_login_model->validatelogin($this->input->post('email'));

        if (!empty($user))
        { 
            $verify_hash = password_verify($this->input->post('password'), $user->userPassword);

            if($user->isActive != 1)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Your accounis is not active contact admin');
                redirect('user/login');
            }
            else if ($verify_hash)
            {
                // login success
                $this->session->set_userdata('uid', $user->id);
                redirect('user/dashboard');
            }
        } 

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid credentials');
        redirect('user/login');
    }
}
```

The Model

```
public function validatelogin($email)
{
    return $this->db->get_where('tblusers', array('emailId' => $email))
        ->row();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sourav, I appreciate you answer. I tried it and the `var_dump(validation_errors());` produced this error when I try to launch it on the browswer `C:\wamp\www\zikshom\zuser\application\controllers\user\Login.php:22:string'' (length=0)`, and the code is actually on line 22 in the file. I am new to codegniter and really don't know how to fix that. I shall be glad your you can further throw more light.

Comment: @ Sourav, how do i upload the screenshot here?

Comment: @ Sourav, I have uploaded it.

Comment: where you uploaded it? I can't see.

Comment: sorry, I have uploaded it.

Comment: Please check your input with **print_r($_POST);exit;** maybe it is form related issue. check the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013794/codeigniter-validation-errors-always-returning-empty

Comment: you can load your view page **$this->load->view('your_login_page');** instead of showing the **validation_errors();**